# In R: How to loop over Names in data_A to pick columns from data_B depending on ColumnNum from data_A?

Tags: r

I want to create a dataframe for Each Agency_Sen in data_A. Each (ColumnNum) from data_A refers to a column from data_B which is Supposed to be the new values for each Agency_Sen:
The code that I am imagining is:

```
for (i in data_A$Agency_Sen) {
  for (j in data_A$ColumnNum) {
    i <- as.data.frame(select(data_B, 1:2, j))
  }
}
```

[data_A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMiXz.png)

[data_B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MljDF.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(data_A$ColumnNum, data_A$Agency_Sen), 
          function(i) cbind(data_B[1:2], data_B[i]))
```

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. What is the name of the identifiers?  Is it `dataA` and `dataB`

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. I changed it to `data_A`, `data_B`

Comment: Thank you so much! that works but I need to keep the first two columns and make each Agency_Sen as a new data frame, is that possible?

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. Did you meant that for each dataset, the first two columns are common?

Comment: The identifiers are (ColumnNum) from data_A

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. The columns are subset based on the 'ColumnNum' only.  You said the `I need to keep the first two columns`.  Is that common in all the datasets?

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. I would recommend to keep the datasets in the `list` itself instead of creating objectss in the global env.

Comment: yes the first two columns are common for all, since they are date and time.

Comment: Dear Akrun: Thank you so much it is really beneficial I just want to keep the first two columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. let me try this. I am sorry because I could not follow the update since it is my first post on stack. appreciate your solution sir it is amazing. Sorry again.

Comment: @MustafaAttallah. As per your earlier commentss, you want the first two columns common and theen the other columns from the CoiumnNum